# Why is Newton's law of restitution true, or how to prove it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

**Question.** If we just consider a one-dimensional collision between two objects (ignore friction as well), Newton's law of restitution states that the speed of separation after the collision divided by the speed of approaching before the collision gives the coefficient of restitution, say $e$, whose value is inclusively between 0 and 1. My question is how this can be proved.

---

**My Thought.** Generally I have no idea how to come out with a proof. Nevertheless, I am thinking about a specific scenario in which object $A$ with mass $m_1$ and speed $v_1$ is hitting object $B$ with mass $m_2$ and zero speed, and after the collision object $A$ stops and object $B$ has speed $v_2$. Now if we suppose there is no loss in kinetic energy during the collision (so elastic collision), and $m_1>m_2$, then it is clear $v_2>v_1$. But $v_2$ is the separation speed while $v_1$ is the approaching speed, and this leads to an $e$ which exceeds $1$, contradicting Newton's law of restitution. If the law is correct, then this cannot happen, but why it can't?

---

**Comment.** Any kind of help including brief hints and formal answers are welcome and will be appreciated.

Comment: The final speed of $m_1$ after the collision cannot be zero; it would either violate energy or momentum conservation laws. Therefore, $v_2$ will not be the separation speed, as $m_1$ will still have some motion after the collision.

Comment: @chris97ong Hi Chris. I am convinced by the momentum law for sure, but the energy conservation may not be applied here because of potential inelastic collision, I think? I am kind of convincing myself of the restitution law from some maybe peculiar angle.

Comment: The law of collisions is an empirical law, and therefor cannot be proven mathematically.

Answer (score 2):

The law is an empirical one- you cannot prove it, as you might a mathematical result, but only check its validity by performing experiments. Indeed, it is often called "Newton's experimental law".

You can, however, derive the result for simple collisions by considering conservation of energy and momentum. You can show, for example, that the coefficient cannot be greater than 1 if energy is to be conserved. You can simplify the job by considering examples in which two bodies colliding have equal mass. For a more general treatment, see, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11903

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am pretty sure that the law can be applied to objects of different masses.

Comment: You are quire right- it was too early in the morning for me!

Comment: I suppose I should edit my answer before I start a huge cascade of misconceptions!

Comment: That linked paper is great. I could have used a hundred more like it when I was a student.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is impossible that the first object stops. Solve the system of equations and you will see possible values of velocities, they are not random. Consider a case of $m_{1} \gg m_{2}$, a brick hitting grain of sand. Can a brick stop in such a case? Obliviously not.

Let's discuss your 1D case.
Initial state: $v_{1i} \ne 0$, $v_{2i} = 0$. After the collision: $v_{1f}$, $v_{2f}$. Writing down energy and momentum conservation laws (in the energy conservation law we cancel $1/2$ on each side):

$$
m_{1}v_{i1}^{2} = m_{1}v_{f1}^{2} + m_{2}v_{f2}^{2},
$$

$$
m_{1}v_{i1} = m_{1}v_{f1} + m_{2}v_{f2}.
$$

Let's introduce $\mu = m_{2} / m_{1}$, express $v_{f1} = v_{i1} - \mu v_{f2}$ from the second equation and substitute into the first one:

$$
v_{i1}^{2} = v_{i1}^{2} - 2 \mu v_{i1} v_{f2} + \mu^{2}v_{f2}^{2} + \mu v_{f2}^{2},
\\
v_{f2} \mu \left( v_{f2} \left( \mu+1 \right) - 2 v_{i1} \right) = 0
$$

That means that energy and momentum are conserved either when $v_{f2} = 0$, meaning that there was no collision at all and the first object just flied along, and in this case $v_{f1} = v_{i1}$, or
$$
v_{f2} = \frac{2}{1 + \mu} v_{i1},
\\
v_{f1} = \frac{1 - \mu}{1 + \mu} v_{i1} = \frac{m_{1} - m_{2}}{m_{1} + m_{2}} v_{i1}
$$

If $m_{1} > m_{2}$, then $v_{f1}$ is strictly positive. That means the heavier object cannot stop when hits the lighter object, it is simply non-physical.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But conservation of energy may not be true, isn't it? Because kinetic energy can be lost if the collision is not elastic, and this is where the restitution thing comes in I think.

Comment: In this case you'll need to add another term, $\varepsilon_{L}$, energy that was lost. It will change the resultant formula, but restitution will be below 1. In case of elastic scattering it is exactly one. Just do the very same thing, but add additional term into energy conservation law, $-\varepsilon_{L}$ on the right.

Comment: Hmm... Then I don't think you can factorize with the extra term.

Comment: Well, you can solve the quadratic equation with the extra (free) term, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

The is an important idea about the [coefficient of restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution#Range_of_values_for_e_%E2%80%93_treated_as_a_constant), $e$, which you may not be aware of.

*I am thinking about a specific scenario in which object $A$ with mass $m_1$ and speed $v_1$ is hitting object $B$ with mass $m_2$ and zero speed, and after the collision object $A$ stops and object $B$ has speed $v_2$.

First consider a collision with a coefficient of restitution $e$.

Linear momentum conservation $\Rightarrow m_1v_1 = m_2v_2$ and definition of coefficient of restitution $e= v_2/v_1$.
Combining these two equations gives $m_2\,e = m_1$.

If the collision is elastic $e=1$ and $m_1=m_2$ is the only possibility.

*. . . this leads to an $e$ which exceeds $1$, contradicting Newton's law of restitution.*

It might **appear** that this means that for your scenario to happen $m_2$ must greater than $m_1$ but in a *super-elastic* collision, eg an explosion, $e$ can be greater than one ie the kinetic energy of a system after collision can be greater than the kinetic energy before the collision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my point here is to see why Newton's restitution law stands in the first place, rather than applying it to disprove my specific scenario (which I know how to prove it wrong if the law holds). One confusion for me would be: why the restitution coefficient cannot be greater than 1?

Comment: @IncredibleSimon $e$ can be greater than one, ie kinetic energy of system does increase in an explosion.  The coefficient of restitution is another way of stating how the kinetic energy changes in a collision, the two ways are equivalent to one another.

Answer (score 0):

mathematical you  solve this collision problem with those three equations

$$m_{{1}} \left( v_{{{\it f1}}}-v_{{{\it i1}}} \right) ={\it dp}\tag 1$$

$$m_{{2}} \left( v_{{{\it f2}}}-v_{{{\it i2}}} \right) =-{\it dp}\tag 2$$

$$v_{{{\it f2}}}-v_{{{\it f1}}}=-\epsilon\, \left( v_{{{\it i2}}}-v_{{{
\it i1}}} \right) 
\tag 3$$

so for a given initial velocities $~v_i~$ the masses $~m_i~$ and restitution parameter $~\epsilon$ you obtain the final velocities after the collision $~v_f~$
and the momentum $~dp~$.
the final velocities are depending on the restitution parameter $~\epsilon$ and the initial velocities and the masses.

**determine the restitution parameter $~\epsilon$ through experiment**

according to  equation (3) is:

$$\epsilon=\frac{v_{f2}-v_{f1}}{v_{i1}-v_{i2}}$$

so all you have to do is to measure the initial and final velocities.

with this result, you can  prove (validate) the  theory, comparing the measurement of the  final velocity with the result that you obtain from the theory.

**notice**

equations (1) and (2) are the modified Newton equations

Answer (score 0):

This is not a law, it's the definition of $e$, with conservation of energy limiting the maximum value.